# The Eclipse Flex plugin deleted my project, any way to recover it?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, eclipse

I just tried to use the Eclipse "move" function to move my project.  Instead of Eclipse moving it, Eclipse deleted my project.  I have most of it backed up, but I will lose a few hours of work if I cannot recover it.

Does anyone know how to recover it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work if you deleted the file, but Eclipse does have a history by default that should have your code in there. This helped me out when the power went out and it overwrote my file with gibberish

EDIT: Ok, I looked in Eclipse, try right clicking the folder and there should be a replace with local history option somewhere in there. See if that'll help.

Comment: I wish I could vote you up 5 points for this.  I thought I was screwed.  I guess we all need the occasional reminder to commit all the time.

Comment: I voted up, the replace with local history option has definitely saved me a few times.

Comment: Awesome tip, everyone needs to know this one (or will need to know one day)